# How to handle Knex update Query within Socket IO event loop

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io, async-await, knex.js

I have a socket listener in my node server and it receives socket events within milliseconds of time and I'm updating the status that I receive in the event data with knex.js with MySql Client. But sometimes it won't update due to the faster event loop.

I have tried async-await but it did not help me. Here is my code. Please help me to sort this thing out.

```
socket.on("orderUpdate", function(message) {
    setImmediate(function(){
        orderModel.updateOrderStatus(message);
    })
 });
```

Here my `updateOrderStatus` method is as follow.

```
updateOrderStatus: async function (data) {
    try {
        return await knex(table_name)
            .where('order_id', data.order_id)
            .update({
                status: data.status,
            })
    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure that you're are getting the socket event. Use [socket acknowledgment](https://socket.io/docs/#Sending-and-getting-data-acknowledgements) to be sure .

2.Print the logs for the query to check if the update was successful.

```
socket.on("orderUpdate", async function (message, callback) {
    let resp = await orderModel.updateOrderStatus(message);
    return callback(resp);
});

socket.emit("orderUpdate", message, (resp) => {
    console.log("resp : ", resp);
});
```

Comment: I do not need to acknowledge the user as it is push-only event structure so I do not need to emit back to the user. Apart from that, whatever data I am getting in socket must update in the database and I have also printed all the logs in orderUpdate event. I don't think there is an issue in WebSocket event.

Comment: Check your update query logs( post your log here )  to verify affected rows because if there is no issue with socket event and you have implemented the socket listener as mentioned in the answer above (async-await) then the code should work assuming that message you're getting from the client is validated as you're not validating the message before passing to updateOrderStatus function.

Comment: I will put it surely. One more thing that if the events come slower, then all the status update perfectly. It only happens in faster events i.e. Three or more events within 5 milliseconds.